# How can I set 'input_shape' of keras.layers.SimpleRNN, when Data is unvariate?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to do time-series forecasting using RNN, but an error continuously occurred in `'input_shape'` of `keras.layers.SimpleRNN`,

but I could not solve it, so I would like to ask a question.

First of all, below is the code. and This is **Error Message**:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 1)
```

```
# X_train.shape = (58118,)
# y_train.shape = (58118,)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2,shuffle=False,random_state=1004)

X_train,X_val,y_train,y_val = train_test_split(X_train,y_train,test_size=0.125,shuffle=False,random_state=1004)

print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    model = keras.models.Sequential([
        keras.layers.SimpleRNN(20, return_sequences=True, input_shape=[None,1]),
        keras.layers.SimpleRNN(20, return_sequences=True),
        keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(10))
    ])

    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20,validation_data=(X_val, y_val)) #Error
    model.save('rnn.h5')
```

Comment: It expects a 3D input as `(batch_size, n_timesteps, n_features)` But you have passed an array with shape `(58118,)`., which is a 1D array.

Comment: Reshape the data to `(1, -1, 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleRNN expects inputs: A 3D tensor, with shape `[batch, timesteps, feature]`

**Sample Code**

```
inputs = np.random.random([32, 10, 8]).astype(np.float32)
simple_rnn = tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(4)

output = simple_rnn(inputs)
```

Output has shape `[32, 4]`.